# How to compare two numbers from a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to create comparison/validation of two numbers for retrieving the right number from the database.

I'm doing using PHP, HTML and retrieve the details of weight from XAMPP database to compare with user input.

I'm using `type='number'` so that user can only input digits.

#### HTML FORM

```
<form action="" method="POST" onSubmit= "return Validator_edit(this)">

            <table class="midTable" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <tr>

            <tr>
            <th align="right" >Weight:</th>
            <td><input type="number" size="20" name="weight" id="weight" value="<?php echo $weight ?>" disabled="disabled"> * Weight that you have set previously <br/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <th align="right" >Progress:</th>
            <td><input type="number" name="progress" value="<?php echo $progress ?>" id="progress" > 
            * NOTE : Progress must NOT exceed the weight you have set .</strong><br></h3></td>
            </tr>

            <tr >
            <td colspan='2' align='center'><input type="submit" value="update" name="submit" />&nbsp; 
            </tr>


            </table>
        </form>
```

#### Validation form

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function Validator_edit(frm){

            if (frm.progress.value=="")
            { 
                alert("progess must not be empty");
                frm.progress.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (frm.progress.value > frm.weight.value )
            {   

                alert(" You have exceed the weight.");
                frm.progress.focus();
                return false;
            }   
     }

    </script>
```

For some reason, it is able to validate "some" numbers. For example: I've set:

```
 Weight = 50
```

logically progress under 50 will be able to be validated and return true.

However, it fails on 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, even though these numbers are less than 50.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: To help debug this, use your console:  add `console.log(frm.progress.value);` and `console.log(frm.weight.value);` as the first lines of your `Validator_edit` function.

Comment: i already tried what @TimMorton suggested. the function able to retrieve the weight from database and user input on the form. however the comparison doesn't really work.

Comment: I don't remember if javascript will easily tell you what type of variable it is: string/float/integer.  Possibly it's comparing it as strings, not as numbers.  If so, you need to change the type to a float or integer.  Off the top of my head I don't remember what the method is; but it would be something like `parseFloat(frm.progress.value) > parseFloat(frm.weight.value)`

Comment: that solves it. thank you so much @TimMorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numbers might be in string forms. You might try using a function such as `Number();` in JavaScript and pass it through that, just to make sure, typeof your **form progress values** are <kbd>number</kbd>.

Maybe, try something similar to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Validator_edit(frm){
            if (frm.progress.value=="")
            { 
                alert("progess must not be empty");
                frm.progress.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (Number(frm.progress.value) > Number(frm.weight.value) )
            {   

                alert(" You have exceed the weight.");
                frm.progress.focus();
                return false;
            }   
     }
</script>
```

---

Or you might pass it through a regex, maybe similar to:

```
function is_number(form_progress_number) {
    return /^\d+$/.test(form_progress_number);
}
```

[This link](https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/check-if-variable-is-a-number-in-javascript/) might help you.